# smart recompose does not work: Compose recompose even though state does not change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I don't understand why clicking the button triggers the Inner Composable's recomposition, if this line `Log.d(Tag, "urls:$urls")` in Wrapper Composable is commented out, the Inner Composable will not recompose.

```kotlin
const val Tag = "Test"

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestComposeTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    var height by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(100.dp)
                    }
                    Column {
                        Button(onClick = { height += 10.dp }) {
                            Text(text = "Click")
                        }

                        val urls = remember { mutableStateListOf("http://www.test.com") }
                        Box(
                            Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(height)
                                .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                        ) {
                            Log.d(Tag, "Main")
                            Wrapper(urls)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun Inner(
    someEventHandler: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    Log.d(Tag, "Inner:someEventHandler hashcode:${someEventHandler.hashCode()}")
}


@Composable
fun Wrapper(
    urls: List<String>,
) {
    Log.d(Tag, "Wrapper: urls hashcode:${urls.hashCode()}")

    Inner(
        someEventHandler = {
            Log.d(Tag, "urls:$urls")
        },
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `List` is not stable.

In order to see this more clearly I added a Text inside your Inner in order to prevent inlining. That way I can properly see the re-compositions and skipped re-compositions in the Layout Inspector.

```
@Composable
private fun Inner(
    someEventHandler: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    Text("TEST")
    Log.d(Tag, "Inner:someEventHandler hashcode:${someEventHandler.hashCode()}")
}
```

This is how it looks with your implementation after clicking one time:

| Recompositions in Layout Inspector when using mutableStateListOf |
| --- |
| [image: Recompositions in Layout Inspector with unstable List] |
| left columns shows # of recompositions, right columns shows # of skipped recompositions |

Now if we replace `mutableStateListOf` with ImmutableList from `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable`:

```
val urls by remember { mutableStateOf(persistentListOf("http://www.test.com")) }
```

This is how it looks now after clicking one time:

| Recompositions in Layout Inspector when using ImmutableList |
| --- |
| [image: Recompositions in Layout Inspector with ImmutableList] |
| left columns shows # of recompositions, right columns shows # of skipped recompositions |

As you can see, this time it skipped recomposing.

For more information refer to: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability/fix

Comment: Thank you for your response,I added a Text in the Inner and used persistentListOf as you said, I also change the Wrapper's parameter type List<String> to ImmutableList<String>, the Inner Composable does not recompose when the Button is clicked. But here comes a new problem: what if I want to add a new item to the remembered urls when the button is clicked?  the Wrapper does not recompose at all.

Comment: it seems that if we choose to use stable list in Jetpack Compose, the only way to update the list is creating a whole new one

Comment: yes! That's exactly the way of doing it. Instead of remember it, you would normally want to push the state down from your ViewModel (or whatever you are yo use to generate the view state). You want to always work with immutable state, and do the state transformation elsewhere. Using mutableStateof is more the exception than the rule. 
You may find this useful too https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The links you provided before and this time are really helpful.